# Jest: `querySelector` returns null in test of a ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm testing a connected functional component in ReactJS using jest and the react-testing-library.

The component renders some input fields and a button. Here's a simplified version of it, in which I decided to leave the full structure of `GridContainer` and `GridItem` components (from Material-UI) as they might play a role in this issue:

```
export function Letter(props) {
  const [letter, setLetter] = useState({
    // not relevant
  });

  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem md={6} sm={6}>
        <GridContainer>
          <GridItem>
            <LetterImageUpload />
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem>
            <LetterText />
          </GridItem>
        </GridContainer>
      </GridItem>
      <GridItem md={6} sm={6}>
        <LetterAddress />
        <GridContainer>
          <Button
            data-testid="AddToStoreButton"
            onClick={() => {
              props.addToStore(letter);
            }}
          >
            Add to Store
          </Button>
        </GridContainer>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addToStore: letter => {
      dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_STORE", payload: letter });
    }
  };
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Letter);
```

As you can see I export both the dumb component *and* the connected component (the latter via `export default`), so that I can just `import { Letter }` in my tests and not bother about the redux store (**is this the right way?**).

The accompanying test goes like this:

```
import { Letter } from "components/Letter/Letter.js";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

test("Letter", () => {
  act(() => {
    render(<Letter addToStore={jest.fn()} />, container);
  });
  // FIXME: querySelector returns null
  container.querySelector('[data-testid="AddToStoreButton"]').simulate("click");
  // assert
});
```

In a debugger I can see that querySelector returns `null` regardless of the selector I used.
For instance, I tried the following in the live debugger:

```
> container.querySelector('[data-testid="AddToCartButton"]')
null
> container.querySelector("button")
null
> container.querySelector("div")
null
```

I'm clearly doing something spectacularly wrong. Can anyone spot it?

Comment: The [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro) I just scanned don't use a `container` like you did, instead an imported `screen` object. The `render()` method also returns an object with a `container` property that can be used for testing the component.

Comment: Interesting. I was following the [testing recipes](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html) from ReactJS.org, but I realise now that the `render` component there comes from `"react-dom"` rather than the react testing library. I'll try and follow your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the tip by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726043/jest-queryselector-returns-null-in-test-of-a-reactjs-component#comment110929663_62726043), it turned out I was using `render` from the react testing library, but actually using as it were the one exported by the "react-dom" library.

The complete solution, [using the react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet) looks like this:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

test("Letter", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Letter addToStore={() => {}} />);
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId("AddToStoreButton"));
  // assert
});
```

Just to add a bit of more context, if you follow the approach shown in the [Testing Recipes on ReactJS.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html), you'll need to `import { render } from "react-dom"`, instead.